# Javascript callbacks and stack overflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have a doubt about the behaviour of NodeJS/Javascript when dealing with callback nesting.

I have the following (simplified) code in a NodeJS app:

```
var request_list = [];

function doSomething(){
  if(request_list.length > 0){
    let r = request_list.shift();

    // Do something with r

    setTimeout( ()=> {doSomething()}, 1000);
  }
}

doSomething();
```

If the request list is filled with a lot of requests, Can we have a stack overflow?

Comment: how long does *"Do something with r"* take?

Comment: Does it matter? Imagine this is only a math operation with r and print the result in the console.

Comment: Only asking because I doubt you would have a stack overflow unless array didn't fit in memory or the operation takes longer than the timeout delay for next one to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will not have a stack overflow in this case. This is because the `doSomething` function returns immediately after scheduling itself for execution.

Also, each `doSomething` function operates on the same `request_list` object, reducing its size by one with each call, until there is no element left in the array So it's not possible for the code to run indefinitely.

I tried to see if there might be a memory problem, so I pushed your example to the limit.

```
var request_list = new Array(10000).fill("a")
var start = Date.now();

function doSomething(){
  if(request_list.length > 0){
    let r = request_list.shift();

    console.log(r);
    // Do something with r

    setTimeout( ()=> {doSomething()}, 1);
  }
}

doSomething();

process.on('exit', () => { console.log('Total time: ' + (Date.now() - start))})
```

I created an array of 10000 elements with a `setTimeout` of 1 ms. The process finished in `Total time: 148020` (about 148 seconds), probably due to the expensive array shift and console.log calls. During this time the total memory of `node` remained constant, so there are no issues there as well.